# Sending messages to nao_controller from rostopic_pub'

Tags: ros, yaml, nao-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Every body ,
I am new in Ros and Python
I would like to use joint_angles  topic to control only on joint of NAO lets say HeadYaw
Id it possible to let me know the procedure?

I was running the following command but it does not work :

rostopic  pub   /joint_angles    nao_msgs/JointAnglesWithSpeed   '{seq: 1, stamp: now, frame_id: Head}'  '['[HeadYaw,HeadPitch]',[1,-1],2.0,0]'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69232/sending-messages-to-nao_controller-from-rostopic_pub%27/) by [Mohsen 2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/5116/mohsen-2013/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2013-07-26**:
Could you change the title to something more descriptive? Eg. 'Sending messages to nao_controller from rostopic_pub'. It'll make it easier for future users to find your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two issues with your command:

- On ROS groovy the line is not being accepted, if you flatten your arrays and add **--** for the negative numbers it works
- The relative speed must be a value between 0 and 1

So if you type something like this...

```
rostopic pub /joint_angles nao_msgs/JointAnglesWithSpeed -- '[ 1, now, Head]' '[HeadYaw,HeadPitch]' '[1,-1]'  1.0  0
```

... it should work (at least on groovy with `nao_controller` up and running)

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen 2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/5116/mohsen-2013/) on 2013-07-26**:
Thanks alot :)